¿Headershow en el Tab.Navigator desde la substack?
Estoy utilizando este tab navigator
 function AppTabs() {
  // Mapeo de iconos y tipos para las pestañas
  const tabIconConfig = {
    Home: { iconName: "home", IconType: Octicons },
    Buscar: { iconName: "search1", IconType: AntDesign },
    Agregar: { iconName: "add-circle-outline", IconType: Ionicons },
    Settings: { iconName: "settings", IconType: MaterialIcons },
    Mapita: { iconName: "map-marker", IconType: FontAwesome },
    Perfil: { iconName: "person", IconType: Ionicons },

  };

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
          const { iconName, IconType } = tabIconConfig[route.name] || {};
          return IconType ? <IconType name={iconName} size={size} color={color} /> : null;
        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: "#d44119",
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: "gray",
        headerTitle: () => (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Image
              source={require("./assets/images/logo/Isologo-naranja.png")}
              style={{ height: 30, width: 100, resizeMode: "contain" }}
            />
          </View>
        ),
        headerRight: () => (
          <FontAwesome
            name="envelope-o"
            size={24}
            color="#AFAFAF"
            style={{ marginRight: 15 }}
            onPress={() => {
              console.log("Messages icon pressed");
            }}
          />
        ),
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Buscar" component={Register} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Agregar" component={Register} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Mapita" component={MapScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Perfil" component={MapScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

Dentro de este mismo tab navigator hay un stack llamado "HomeStackScreen".
function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="HomeMain"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="Post"
        component={PostScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: "Post" }}
      />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

Ahora la problematica es la siguiente:
Yo quiero que el header del Tab.Navigator se muestre en Home no en post ya que va a tener su propio header con el titulo 'Post'.
Sucede que si se lo oculto al Home, tambien se lo oculto al Post.
¿Como puedo hacer para que el Header del Tab.Navigator se oculte al detectar que esta en Post pero no se oculte al estar en Home?

ACTUALIZACION
Aca esta el stack screen del post que se me ocurrio para poder darle una navegacion al Tab Post.
function PostStackScreen() {
  return (
    <PostStack.Navigator>
      <PostStack.Screen
        name="Post"
        component={PostScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false}}
      />
    </PostStack.Navigator>
  );
}

En esta parte esta el post nuevo que se me ocurrio agregar
  <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Buscar" component={Register} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Agregar" component={Register} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Mapita" component={MapScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen
    name="Post"
    component={PostStackScreen}
    options={{
      tabBarButton: () => null,
      headerTitle: () => null
    }}
  />

Esto es una buena practica? Es una manera que se me ocurrio para poder evitar que muestre el header del tab pero que navegue a post sin mostrar le icono en el Tab.
Es decir...
Evite que el Tab.Screen Post se muestre en el Tab y luego desde home al presionar una publicacion navegue a ese Tab, al estar en ese tab lee los options que posee y desde estos "oculta" los respectivos headers.

Descarta Post de Home, creas otro componente para post  <Tab.Screen name="Post" component={HomeStackScreen} />, ¿Cada uno tiene su propio header no?

Claro me hiciste tener una idea...
Pero mira, ahora edito la pregunta, no se si es una buena practica lo que hice

Ahi lo actualice
